# No soy capaz de crear un proyecto de Angular fuera del directorio en el que me inicia el CMD

Tags: angular, cmd

estoy intentando iniciar mis andaduras por Angular y me sale el error de:
*"ng" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.*

Esto me ocurre siempre que me salgo del directorio C:\Users\"usuario".
Alguna idea?
Un saludo

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. en español. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, puedes hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ganar tu primera medalla. En cuanto a tu pregunta, puede haber varias causas, pero me parece que no has instalado `ng` de forma global: `npm install -g @angular/cli`. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar en angular cli de manera global. Imagino que lo instalaste solo al nivel de la carpeta de tu proyecto. Reinstala angular de manera global, asi:

npm install -g @angular/cli